# Variable-infrastructure:best way to implement custom "handlers"

Tags: python, variables, plugins, architecture

I'm creating an infrastructure for a Digital Life Assistant(a bit like like Siri). The application is supposed to be highly extensible, using plugins written in Python. The entire system shares a tree of variables. The variables are not stored using a Python-type, rather using a custom "Variable" type. Variables have getvalue and setvalue-methods. You could for example do`var=Variable();var.setvalue('child1','thisvalue')`
, but also `var.setvalue('child1.child2','othervalue')`.
To retrieve a value `var.getvar('child1.child2').getvalue()`, but also `var1=var.getvar('child1');var1.getvar('child2').getvalue()`. Getvar returns a Variable-instance of a child-variable, getvalue takes no arguments, and returns the type in which the variable was stored.(e.g. str or int).

I want to implement a system in which a Variable instance can do more: for example, one could create a Variable that returns the current datetime, or fetch some data from a website. I do not want to use a callback system like Twisted's Deferred does.

I've thought about having the developer just inherit the Variable class, and override the getvalue and/or setvalue and/or getvar methods, however, this does not feel "right". I think there's a more elegant solution. Ideally, but not necessarily, the Variable's getvalue, etc methods can be changed/added after creation.

How do other projects do this? Is there perhaps some other project I can look into to see how that project does this sort of thing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your question, it sounds like Variables represent nodes in your hierarchy which contain mutable values, so I agree that it doesn't seem right to subclass Variable in order to implement a different mechanism for fetching its value.

Ignoring the data structure and the get/set interface, I would suggest this architecture:

```
class Variable(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, ValueProducer):
            raise TypeError("Expected a ValueProducer.")
        self.__value = value

    def getValue(self):
        return self.__value.produce() if self.__value else None

    def setValue(self, value):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, ValueProducer):
            raise TypeError("Expected a ValueProducer.")
        self.__value = value


class ValueProducer(object):

    def produce(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class SimpleValueProducer(ValueProducer):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def produce(self):
        return self.__value


class HttpRequestValueProducer(ValueProducer):

    def __init__(self, url, params, method="GET"):
        self.__url = url
        self.__params = params
        self.__method = method

    def produce(self):
        # Implementation omitted.
        return "Stub for HTTP request: " \
             + ", ".join((self.__url, str(self.__params), self.__method)


>>> v1 = Variable(SimpleValue("foo"))
>>> print v1.getValue()
foo

>>> v1.setValue(HttpRequestValue("http://localhost:8080", {"bar": "baz"}))
>>> print v1.getValue()
Stub for HTTP request: http://localhost:8080, {'bar': 'baz'}, GET

>>> v1.setValue("test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test3.py", line 13, in setValue
    raise TypeError("Expected a ValueProducer.")
TypeError: Expected a ValueProducer.

>>> v2 = Variable()
>>> print v2.getValue()
None
```

The reason I would use a class for ValueProducer along with subclasses implementing its interface is to promote some re-usability, especially for values which require a lot of code to retrieve.

On a side note, the path syntax for getting and setting values in your question seems a little awkward: it feels more natural to find a node and set its value directly, rather than combining the search and set operation in parent.setValue(path, value). It may be worth looking into using a tree data structure from a library rather than reinventing it.

Hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: I really like your solution. It is much more intuitive to treat special handlers as objects, rather than as functions, which I was originally planning to do. This way(using objects) it resembles Pythons built-in types(e. g. "That variable is an int", or "that variable is an HttpRequest"). Thanks for your help.